# Can Twilio route non call messages?

Tags: twilio

For example lets say you want to build a chat application and a phone application all in one using Twilio. It would be handy if one could say route the chat(s) the same way as one might route a phone call. Can this be done currently? And if not, any idea if it's on the roadmap, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately this is not something you can do with Twilio today.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any idea if this is on the road map? Or even where one could find the road map?